# How to iterate over object array in angular but display only property with {{}}?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Suppose we have an object array:

```
    var items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'name1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'name2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'name3'
  }
];
```

and we want to iterate over it in HTML using this:

```
{{ctrl.items}}
```

expecting this in the UI:

```
name1, name2, name3
```

Is this possible? Or do I have to use a ngRepeat for that?

I want to mainly do this to take advantage of the limitTo filter inside the {{}}

Comment: your question isn't exactly clear.  yes, you would use `ng-repeat`, and `limitTo` works perfectly fine in an `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using both ng-repeat and the limitTo filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: 3">{{ item.name }}</div>
```

**EDIT**:

[Here is a working plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/0WnCSit7nKu6lzwuaRu9)

Comment: How would you implement the commas in between each item? Without a comma after the last item.

Answer (score 3):

you can use code like this in your HTML

```
{{ctrl.getNames(ctrl.items)}}
```

and in your controller add this function

```
this.getNames = function(items){
     return items.map(function(item){return item.name;}).join(", ");
}
```

or you can make a filter for this ,,

```
app.filter("names",function(){
   return function(input){
      return input.map(function(item){return item.name;}).join(", ");
   };
});
```

and in your HTML use this

```
{{ctrl.items | names}}
```

Comment: Simplest solution(s) for including the commas

Comment: Would {{ctrl.items | names | limitTo: 2}} be valid?

Comment: you should use limitTo filter before names filter so it would be like this
{{ctrl.items | limitTo: 2 | names}}